# Seaborn lineplot hue input could not be interpreted

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to plot my dataframe as a lineplot.
The data is 2D movement data of x and y coordinates.
The dataframe has a column which identifies the data of each individual by a unique ID and a column that identifies the test group of the individual and an additional relevant column that shows the timepoints.

```
    index  Location_Center_Y  unique_id Location_Center_X    classifier
0       0            872.044  B21                     0.000      ctrl
1       1            868.727  B21                    -3.317      ctrl
2       2            864.918  B21                    -7.126      ctrl
3       3            866.462  B21                    -5.582      ctrl
```

I do want to display the data of each individual in a lineplot and want the lines to have different colours based on the test group.
Getting each individual as a single track I achieved by plotting the data of each individual at a time.

I tried using the input units='unique_id' but this unfortunately only works for seaborn.scatterplot. When using it with seaborn.lineplot it raises the error 
    "ValueError: Could not interpret input 'unique_id'"
But whatever, looping works. However I want it coloured by the different groups (classifier column). This should be doable by using the input argument hue='classifier'.

```
#looping through the individuals
for n in data.cells:
    ix=data.tracks[data.tracks['unique_id']==n]
    ax=sns.lineplot(ix['Location_Center_X_Zeroed'],
    ix['Location_Center_Y_Zeroed'], hue='classifier')
```

However, again this raises the error 
    "ValueError: Could not interpret input 'unique_id'".
 So I have no idea how to group my plot.

[I should get something like this but with only 2 colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ7gH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be sure since you didn't provide enough data for me to directly try it out, but it seems like this is what you are looking for?

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Location_Center_X', y='Location_Center_Y', 
             hue='classifier', units="unique_id", estimator=None)
```